# How to make a Batch File Move another File?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I am trying to make a batch script that moves a file into a startup folder and I want to make it universal

Currently I have this but I want to make it work on any user's computer (C:\users\USERNAME)
Here is the code

```
@echo off
color A0

echo Startup...
echo Startup..
echo Startup.
echo Startup
echo Startup.
echo Startup..
echo DONE
echo your name is %name%

move C:%user%\Desktop\Directory 1\dile.txt C:%user%\Desktop\Directory 1\file folder 1

:end
cmd /k
```

The file is called dile.txt located in a folder called Directory 1 on the desktop and I want to make it move to a folder called file folder 1 inside the Directory 1 folder. Is there a way to do this while making it work on anyone's computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of providing something a little bit different:

```batch-file
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set /P "=Startup . " 0< NUL
For /L %%G In (1,1,5) Do (Set /P "=. " 0< NUL
    %SystemRoot%\System32\PATHPING.EXE 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 500 1> NUL)
Echo(&Echo Your name is %UserName%
%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Directory 1" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Directory 1\file folder 1" "dile.txt" /Mov 1> NUL 2>&1
Pause
```

This uses some animated text, `%UserProfile%`, instead of `C:\Users\%UserName%`, and [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) instead of `Move`. Using `RoboCopy`, allows for the creation of your destination directory, if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 1):

%USERNAME% can be used to grab the active user account. Try something like this. Make sure to enclose paths in quotes when folders have spaces in their names.

```
@echo off
color 0A

echo Startup...
echo Startup..
echo Startup.
echo Startup
echo Startup.
echo Startup..
echo DONE
echo your name is %USERNAME%

move "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Directory 1\file.txt" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Directory 1\file folder 1\"

:end
cmd /k
```

Comment: also useful: `%USERPROFILE%`.